# Is there a natural way to prove trig identities also hold for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

In complex analysis trig functions are defined via $\exp$ which in turn is defined via power series. It's of course easy to see that on $\Bbb R$, all these functions agree with their usual real-variable versions that we are well familiar with.

In the real case there are some basic identities like $\cos$ is even, $\sin$ is odd and $\cos(x)=\sin(\frac\pi 2 -x)$ etc. There are also more complicated ones like 
$$\cos(x-y)=\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y.\tag{1}$$

Q1: do real variable identities like $(1)$ also hold when $x,y$ are complex numbers? (Of course, identities involving square roots are not included here. We basically only care about $\cos(x\pm y), \sin(x\pm y)$ etc.

Q2: if so, is there any natural (or slick) way to see this, other than going down to the basic $\exp$ definition and calculating term by term?

Thanks!

Comment: An idea that just struck me: using the uniqueness of extension of holomorphic functions. I'm trying to flesh it out.

Comment: Usually you show (LHS)-(RHS) is a holomorphic function, that is zero on the real line.  It is thus zero everywhere.

Comment: @SteveD sooooo slick! Thanks. I was just thinking about first fixing one variable as real, flexing the other over $\Bbb C$ and then flexing both. But yours is definitely better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer my own question. I'll take $\cos(x-y)$ as an example. For simplicity we denote the identity $(1)$ as 
$$\cos(x-y)=f(x,y),\tag{*}$$ where $f(x,y)$ is the **RHS** expression.

Fix $x\in \Bbb R$. Consider the map $\Bbb C\ni z\mapsto \cos(x-z)$ which is clearly holomorphic. When $z\in \Bbb R$, $\cos(x-z)=f(x,z)$ holds. But $f(x,z)$ is also holomorphic, so $\cos(x-z)=f(x,z)$ must hold throughout the whole $z\in\Bbb C$ domain.

Now we have shown that when $x\in \Bbb R,\,y\in\Bbb C$, $(*)$ will hold. We fix $y$ as *any* complex number, and consider the map $\Bbb C\ni z\mapsto f(z,y)$, and apply the extension argument one more time, then we conclude that $(*)$ always hold even when both variables are complex.

Key point: since $\Bbb R$ has a sequence of distinct points that converges in itself, the extension of a holomorphic function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C$ is unique.

Comment: This is essentially right.  Usually, it's easier to write $f_x(z) = \cos(x-z)-(\cos x\cos z-\sin x\sin z)$, show $f_x(z)$ for the function (so you're just showing $f_x(z)$ is zero on some set with a limit point, so the identity holds on this set).  This is mostly a matter of taste I think though.

Comment: @Mark yeah I think we're saying the same thing. It's just that I used something like a lambda function without naming it.